# What does a tilde between angle brackets mean?

Tags: phonology, notation

I was reading the Wikipedia page for vietnamese phonology and in the vowel chart, it says "/iə̯/ ⟨ia~iê⟩    /ɨə̯/ ⟨ưa~ươ⟩   /uə̯/ ⟨ua~uô⟩. What do the tildes mean?

Answer (score 6):

A tilde generally indicates alternation or variation: "all of these options are possible and acceptable". In angle brackets, it indicates variation in spelling. So, ⟨ưa⟩ and ⟨ươ⟩ are both possible spellings of /ɨə̯/.

Comment: Isn't that what a comma represents?

Comment: @Flagsiscool — Note that your question wasn't about a comma. A zillion other symbols can represent the idea of “or”, like three or two dots, or a slash, or whatever, but a tilde `~` does really represent that idea, too. Please, don't blame us, it wasn't we who wrote that Wiki article.

Comment: If a comma is used inside slashes or square brackets, as in [x, y], it means "[x] and [y] separately", whereas "[x~y]" means "varies between [x] and [y]".

Comment: @Nardog Do you have a reference for that? Couldn't spot it at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Pronunciation or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:IPA but it sounds like the kind of thing that ought to be mentioned in one of those?